# Regression power analysis: R's `pwr::pwr.f2.test` R2 deviation from zero vs. R2 increase (vs. G*Power)?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, statistical-power, f-test, gpower

This question is about the difference between `R`'s `pwr::pwr.f2.test` and `G*Power` regarding the estimation of a required sample size based on given power (a priori power analysis).

In `G*Power`, you can perform the power analysis for the **whole model** with `Test family` = `F tests` and `Statistical test` = `Linear multiple regression: Fixed model, R2 deviation from zero`.

[image]

The equivalent in `R` is the `pwr.f2.test` function:

```
# u = number of predictors
u = 3

# determine v
library(pwr)
(v <- pwr.f2.test(u = u, v = , f2 = 0.25, sig.level = .05, power = .80)$v)
[1] 43.70444

# Determine required sample size
ceiling(v + u + 1)
[1] 48
```

Same results as `G*Power`. So far so good.

But if, instead of testing a whole model, I want to test a **single predictor**, in `G*power` I would go with `Test family` = `F tests` and `Statistical test` = `Linear multiple regression: Fixed model, R2 increase`. Notice that there now is a new box called `Total number of predictors`.

[image]

So what is the equivalent `R` function for `G*Power`'s `R2 increase` variant? I don't see how to specify `Total number of predictors` in `pwr.f2.test`. Is it even possible? What workaround do you guys use? Does it even matter from a statistical point of view?